# Could not find a 'KafkaServer' entry in the JAAS configuration error

Tags: apache-kafka, jaas, sasl

When setting up Kafka with SASL_PLAINTEXT authentication, I am getting
[image]

I did come across [Kafka Server - Could not find a 'KafkaServer' in JAAS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54100125/kafka-server-could-not-find-a-kafkaserver-in-jaas) and [Unable to start Kafka Server using SASL_PLAINTEXT authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60128639/unable-to-start-kafka-server-using-sasl-plaintext-authentication) but the answers in them didn't work for me. So, any new insights would help me. Thanks.

Please find the configurations below.

The `server.properties`

```
broker.id=0
listeners=INTERNAL://127.0.0.1:9092
advertised.listeners=INTERNAL://127.0.0.1:9092
listener.security.protocol.map=INTERNAL:SASL_PLAINTEXT
num.network.threads=3
num.io.threads=8
socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600
log.dirs=/tmp/kafka-logs
num.partitions=1
num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1
offsets.topic.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.min.isr=1
log.retention.hours=168
log.segment.bytes=1073741824
inter.broker.listener.name=INTERNAL

log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000
zookeeper.connect=127.0.0.1:2181
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=18000
group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms=0
delete.topic.enable=true
sasl.enabled.mechanisms=SCRAM-SHA-256
sasl.mechanism.inter.broker.protocol=SCRAM-SHA-256
ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm=
```

The `kafka_server_jaas.conf`

```
KafkaServer {
   org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required
   username="admin"
   password="123456";
   };
Client {
   org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required
   username="admin"
   password="123456";
   };
```

The command I executed.

```bash
export KAFKA_OPTS="-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/home/username/kafka/config/kafka_server_jaas.conf"
sudo bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties #In Kafka folder
```

When I printed `KAFKA_OPTS` using `echo $KAFKA_OPTS` I got `-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/home/kafka/kafka/config/kafka_server_jaas.conf` as the result.

Comment: You don't need sudo to run Kafka

Comment: I was facing few other permissions denied errors, hence I used `sudo`.

Comment: Such as? I think if the JAAS file cannot be read, due to file permissions, you'll get a similar error. Ideally, kafka server runs as its own user account

Comment: I created one user for Kafka, it is now working without sudo, but the error I mentioned still persists.

Comment: I followed this tutorial. Can you recommend any other tutorial for me to setup authentication?

Comment: I'm not sure what tutorial you're referring to, but the Confluent documentation on Kafka security seems to be very detailed. Also, rather than echo, use `ps -ef  | grep Kafka` and look at the actual process arguments

Comment: Sorry! I forgot to add the link of the tutorial I am following https://codeforgeek.com/how-to-set-up-authentication-in-kafka-cluster/

Comment: Sure, I will try what you suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using Kafka `3.5.0`. I now tried `3.0.0`, everything is working just fine.

Comment: I know that this is not technically the correct answer but this may help atleast one person